# Set PK as a combined string of table 1 and 2 records

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Say, for example, I have 2 tables - Table 1 is Drink Type and Table 2 is Flavor. What is the query to create the unique identifier column which would result to drink_type_drink_flavor?

```
+-------------+-------------------+
| drink_type  | drink_flavor      |
+-------------+-------------------+
| Fruity      | Apple             |
| Coffee      | Caramel           |
```

Expected PK for above would be Fruity_Apple and Coffee_Caramel

Comment: sorry for the lost of proper words to describe this, will try my best - basically, I need to set up a new column on that table and records will serve as PK. Would like it to be in the form of "fruity_apple" which is combination of of col1 and col2 values. Will try what you have provided, I think you got the point anyway based on your suggestion :)

Comment: It sounds like you want to allow Fruity Banana ?  And Fruity Caramel ?  `ALTER TABLE foo ADD PRIMARY KEY(drink_type, drink_flavor);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I made it sound too complicated! But here's what I did:

I added a new column first:

```
ALTER TABLE drink ADD COLUMN dtype_dflavor VARCHAR(50);
```

Then used the UPDATE and SET to do it:

```
UPDATE drink SET dtype_dflavor = concat(drink_type, '_', drink_flavor);
```

Then added constraint to set it as PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a proper `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE drink 
    ADD CONSTRAINT drink_pk
        PRIMARY KEY 
        (drink_type, drink_flavor);`
```

If you often want the concatenation of the 2 columns in query results, you can use a view or a generated column (depending on MySQL version).